# Terminal not displaying directory, commands executing instantly when pasted; arrow up ==> ^[[A

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, gnome-terminal, users

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
I created the user "dom" when I first set up Ubuntu. From then, I created another user, named "schule" that also had sudo rights. Here is how I created the account:

```bash
sudo useradd -m schule 
sudo su
usermod -aG sudo schule
```

The terminal on schule is extremely weird:

- it doesn't show the directory you're in
- it doesn't show username@computername
- when you paste commands they instantly execute (except sudo commands)
- if you try to use `ARROW_UP` to get your last command back, it instead puts `^[[A` in the console.
- if you try to use `ARROW_DOWN` to go down in your command history, it instead puts `^[[B` in the console
- it is just a blank `$` and then nothing afterwards

Tried some stuff, including resetting the `.bashrc` file, or copying the contents of dom's bashrc into schule's bashrc but nothing worked.
Here is how it looks when you try to type a command, and then use arrow up:
[image]

I even tried creating another user, named "test" but the terminal also acts weird on there. The terminal is completely fine on dom. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "clone the Dom" account? Did you use the system tools or did you manually copy files?
And how did you create the Dom account, which is as per your post a root account? Ubuntu has no root account by default. Did you tweak the system to get a true root account? If so: how?

Comment: try `sudo apt purge gnome-terminal` and then `sudo apt install gnome-terminal` to reset the gnome-terminal.

Comment: @noisefloor I overhauled the question, it should be much clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useradd is only for basic usage, so I'd suggest you are using `adduser` instead.

First delete your new user (the one you tested) with

```
deluser --remove-home schule
```

**Notice: Use this command with care. Deleting your main user (dom) is not a good idea.**

Then try to create a user with its own home directory:

```
adduser -m -G sudo,adm,cdrom,video,lpadmin,dip,plugdev,sambashare schule
```

(you might not have all those groups, but those above I usually need to have a fullblown admin account)

log out and into the "schule" account.

Comment: Please warn the OP and future readers of  permanent data loss in the deleted user's home directory.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the data gets lost if the command is literally named "DELETE USER"

Comment: @User1986 Not necessarily if the option `--remove-home` isn’t passed … Alternatively the option `--backup` can be added to automatically backup data before deletion … It’s a fact that some readers focus on solving the problem in the question and copy/paste commands to later discover their valuable data disappeared forever … This site is accessible to beginner Ubuntu users as well hence the need for a fair warning :-)

Comment: As the OP seems to be German-speaking (at least that's what I'm guessing from some of the sames), you may also want to read [https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/adduser/](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/adduser/). The 2nd paragraph has some additional info on `adduser` vs. `useradd` ob Ubuntu.

Comment: @Raffa He was supposed to delete the faulty user "schule", not his main user. Still good advice, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The default shell given to a new user is  `sh` not `bash` which is the default shell on Ubuntu ...  I would delete the user and recreate using

```
sudo deluser --remove-home  schule  #  delete user

sudo useradd -m  -s /bin/bash  schule  #  create user and give bash
```

New user will have a file `~/.bashrc`   .... to give a nice terminal prompt which shows the current dir add following to the bottom of the user's `~/.bashrc` file

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ '
```

Comment: Please warn the OP and future readers of  permanent data loss in the deleted user's home directory.